# How to merge incoming data with existing data?

Tags: storage

Let's say I have a struct called `MyStruct` and it looks like this.

```
pub struct MyStruct<> {
    pub name: Vec<u8>,
    pub email: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    pub username: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}
```

In this case, first I insert `MyStruct` with the required `name` field. Later, I call the same function with optional `email` and `username` fields.

I can insert data to `MyStorageMap`. However, how can one mutate the data if data exist and merge the new data with existing data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either do `get` and `insert` like:

```
let mut value = MyStorageMap::<T>::get(key);
value.email = new_email;
value.username = new_username;
MyStorageMap::<T>::insert(value);
```

Or you can simply do a `mutate`:

```
MyStorage::<T>::mutate(key, |value| {
    value.email = new_email;
    value.username = new_username;
});
```

In this context, they are basically the same thing.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do check if `Option` is `None`, put `Some(new_email)`?

Comment: You could write `value.email.get_or_insert_with(|| new_email);`